# transpose column as header and append a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

i'm trying to create a transposed table in csv from scraping html page. after extract data, i've create a dataframe header, but i can't append a row. How to do it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
############
abnt_url = 'https://www.abntcatalogo.com.br/norma.aspx?ID=438348'
abnt_table_col_a = pd.DataFrame([])
abnt_table_col_b = pd.DataFrame([])
norm_page = requests.get(abnt_url)
#########################################################
soup = BeautifulSoup(norm_page.content, 'lxml')
soup.prettify()
#######################
aux_table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_cphPagina_upNorma'})    
aux_table = aux_table.findNext()
col_a = aux_table.findAll('td', {'class':'style6'})
col_b = aux_table.findAll('td', {'style': 'padding-left: 10px'})
###############################################
for i in col_a:
    abnt_table_col_a = abnt_table_col_a.append([i.get_text(strip=True)])
for i in col_b:
    abnt_table_col_b = abnt_table_col_b.append([i.get_text(strip=True)])
```

the problem to transpose the table is in the next 2 lines of code:

```
abnt_table = pd.DataFrame(columns =  abnt_table_col_a)
abnt_table = abnt_table.append(abnt_table_col_b)
```

printing the result:

```
print(abnt_table.to_markdown)
```

RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
return Index.union(this, other, sort=sort).astype(object, copy=False)

```
+=======================+=========+=....    
(Data de Publicação :,) |    .... |
+=======================+=========+=....    
NaN                     | NaN ... | 25/03/2020
NaN                     | NaN ... | Resíduos de serviços de saúde ...
```

expected table:

```
+====================+=================================+=....
| Data de Publicação |               Título :          |
+====================+=================================+=....
| 25/03/2020         | Resíduos de serviços de saúde...|
+--------------------+---------------------------------+-....
```

Comment: Hi it would greatly help if you could provide additional information like: error message, expected output and current output

Comment: I edited the question trying to clarify the problem

Comment: Please form a **minimal reproducible example** from the sample code/text and while doing so, please translate **non-English text**.